# Starting app with Process.Start does not show in Task Manager until main application exits

Tags: taskmanager, process.start

I start a small application from my main application using process.start.  Here is an abstract of my code: (I removed all the error-checking just for clarity...)

```
        Dim proc as New Process

        Dim si As New ProcessStartInfo

        si.FileName = "SourceMonitor.exe"

        si.Arguments = "guid=" & GUID & " name=" & Name & " timeout=0"

        si.UseShellExecute = True

        si.CreateNoWindow = True

        Proc.StartInfo = si

        Proc.EnableRaisingEvents = True

        AddHandler Proc.Exited, AddressOf procExitEventHandler

        Proc.Start()
```

What happens is that the new app **SourceMonitor** will not show up in Task Manager - but I want it to.  *However*, it **Does show up** as soon as the program that launched it (using process.start) exits.  This seems odd to me!
I've tried setting UseShellExecute to False, and even tried a different approach using si (my ProcessStartInfo) to

```
WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
si.UseShellExecute = False 'this is required when using processWindowStyle.hidden
```

In every case the app does **not** show up in Task Manager until the main program exits.
Does anyone know of a way to make sure my app does show up in Task Manager? It helps when I need to diagnose a customer issue - because I need to see if the SourceMonitor is running.

Comment: I suspect it isn't missing, just not where you expect to see it. Perhaps it got grouped with your main program.

Comment: Yes - that was indeed the case. Not sure if this is something new in one of the numerous Windows 10 update, but it kind works well for me. The new process does show up as a sub-process to the main application. If the main application is ended then it slides down to the list of all the independent processes.

Answer (score 1):

Ok - found the "issue" - and it was rather obvious...
The second process is owned by the first. It doesn't show up in the list as an independent process, rather it shows up as a child of the main process. The Task Manager has a drop-down arrow on the main application.

```
v  MainApplication
   - SourceMonitor
```

Clicking the dropdown shows the SourceMonitor it shelled.   If I stop the main application the SourceMonitor does become an independent app and then shows up on the regular list.  This actually works better than I had hoped.